# Why is there type mismatch of operator and operand?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Why is there a tycon mismatch operator and operand do not agree error? Any Suggestion for a solution?

```
fun reve (x:string) = implode o rev o explode x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in, that function application binds stronger than `o`.

That is, it is interpreted as:

```
fun reve x = implode o rev o (explode x);
```

Since `explode x` is a `char list` and not a function, this will fail.

You can fix this by placing your parentheses properly

```
fun reve x = (implode o rev o explode) x;
```

Or writing it in point-free notation:

```
val reve = implode o rev o explode
```

It's also possible to define a right-associative function application operator, usually called `$`, which does what you want without parentheses:

```
(* Right-associative function application *)
infixr $
fun f $ x = f x;

fun reve x = implode o rev o explode $ x
```